# I can't install package because of conflict dependecy

Tags: python

I try install a package in python with cmd. but, i to counter this error: ERROR: Cannot install liionpack==0.3, liionpack==0.3.1 and liionpack==0.3.2 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies. and they wrote this message for me to fix:

1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict.              i search and try this solution, but i dont make. and i installed venv again, remove other package version..                                                                             what is your suggestion? thx.

Comment: Why are you trying to install 3 different versions of the same package?

Comment: i don't try 3 different versions of package, i was try a specific version install but again get error.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it only works with python 3.9.
I have python 3.9.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33830720)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).